# Raspberry Pi trigger signal time stamps

Tags: gpio

I need to generate a trigger signal (square wave) with up to 200 Hz for a sensor. For every rising edge of the signal I need to save (ideally publish as a ROS msg) the UTC time stamp. For this I want to synchronize the system clock of a Raspberry Pi using a GPS receiver utilizing its PPS output. Then, I want to use a GPIO pin to create the trigger signal while saving the current system time of the Pi whenever I set the pin to high.

This leaves me with some questions:

- What is the response time of the pin from executing the code command of setting it high to its output actually going high?
- What can I do to get the system time as close as possible to the pin switching event?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried?  The measurements you have made will let us know if your results are as good as can be achieved.

Comment: What precision do you **require**?

Comment: @Milliways sub 1 ms is required, sub 10us would be ideal

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which language & library you use you can toggle (2 writes) a GPIO more than 5,000,000 times a second so you have sub microsecond timing.

Comment: What I am concerned about is the accuracy of a saved time stamp with regards to when the physical pin has reached the HIGH state. I cannot find any documentation on that